# How to create sparse boolean mask in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, numpy, sparse-matrix

I have the following code for mask filtering of df :

```
for i, y in enumerate(cols) :
    dfm = df[y].str.contains(s)
    mask= dfm if i==0 else np.column_stack((mask, dfm))
```

df is not sparse, but the filtering results mask is sparse.

Storing the mask in full boolean consumes a lot of memory when having a large dataframe ( 50mio rows * 100columns).

So, as mask result is very sparse (0.1% is TRUE), wondering if there is a way to use sparse boolean mask instead of array mask in order to reduce memory load...

Could not find any solution even there is already sparse array in Pandas.
Since this is not clear how to use it for the mask storage and usage.
ie

```
mask_sparse = pd.SparseArray(mask)
```

EDIT 2: Clarification of the question :
  Can we get directly the filter result mask into a sparse array
  without manipulating the full array  ?

Comment: I'm very confused.  You need to put more effort into explaining what you have, want, and have tried.  read this to get a better idea how to maximize your chance of having your question answered... [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: thx, I have edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523861/can-pandas-sparseseries-store-values-in-the-float16-dtype is the only SO question I find that discusses `pd.SparseArray`.  There are a few others that deal with sparse dataframes or series.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41505416/efficient-way-to-set-elements-to-zero-where-mask-is-true-on-scipy-sparse-matrix is about masking using the `scipy` sparse matrices.  Even with those simpler objects it isn't trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You can create sparse dataframes easily.  But there is one major gotcha!

Consider the following dataframe `df` and its memory footprint

```
# 10,000 cells with 1% ones and 99% zeros
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice((0, 1), size=(10000, 1000), p=(.99, .01)))
df.memory_usage().sum()

80000080
```

Let's try to sparsify

```
df_sparse = df.to_sparse()
df_sparse.memory_usage().sum()

80000080
```

Hmmm, that didn't do anything.  That's because, we need to specify the object that is the majority place holder.  Let's see

```
df_sparse_2 = df.to_sparse(1)
df_sparse_2.memory_usage().sum()

79196744
```

And

```
df_sparse_3 = df.to_sparse(0)
df_sparse_3.memory_usage().sum()

803416
```

That's better.  Make sure to specify the place holder value.

Comment: Thx, this is not the dataframe df itself which is not sparse, but the boolean mask resulting of the filtering which is sparse.

Comment: @deepmind27 just apply this idea to `mask`.  `mask = mask.to_sparse(False)`

Comment: How do you use this mask?